# application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler not called on iOS 11 with Production Certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios11

I am facing below issue in **iOS11 Only**

> PushNotification Not working with **Production Certificate**
>
> PushNotification is working with **Development Certificate**

```
{
    "aps":{
        "content-available":1
    }
}
```

However it is working for Both Development & Production for below payload

```
{
    "aps":{
        "alert":"Test",
        "content-available":1
    }
}
```

Comment: from where to you send notification?

Comment: I m using knuff.app for sending push notifications!

Comment: https://pushtry.com/ please try this site